# Spring Integration call another handler method after aggregation

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-integration

I am developing a system which will read and process file from a directory. Once all the file has been processed it will call a method which in turn generates a file. Also, it should route/process the files based on file name, I have used spring integration router for the same. Below is the code snippet of the Integration. My question is, this is not working if I remove any of the line `.channel(aggregatorOutputChannel())` or `.channel(confirmChannel())`, also I have to keep the same channel `.channel(aggregatorOutputChannel())` before and after the aggregator. Why do I need all 3 channel declaration? if this is wrong how to correct it.

I am using JDK 8, Spring 5, Spring boot 2.0.4.

```
@Configuration
@EnableIntegration
public class IntegrationConfig {

    @Value("${agent.demographic.input.directory}")
    private String inputDir;

    @Value("${agent.demographic.output.directory}")
    private String outputDir;

    @Value("${confirmationfile.directory}")
    private String confirmDir;

    @Value("${input.scan.frequency: 2}")
    private long scanFrequency;

    @Value("${processing.waittime: 6000}")
    private long messageGroupWaiting;

    @Value("${thread.corepoolsize: 10}")
    private int corepoolsize;

    @Value("${thread.maxpoolsize: 20}")
    private int maxpoolsize;

    @Value("${thread.queuecapacity: 1000}")
    private int queuedepth;

    @Bean
    public MessageSource<File> inputFileSource() {
        FileReadingMessageSource src = new FileReadingMessageSource();

        src.setDirectory(new File(inputDir));
        src.setAutoCreateDirectory(true);

        ChainFileListFilter<File> chainFileListFilter = new ChainFileListFilter<>();
        chainFileListFilter.addFilter(new AcceptOnceFileListFilter<>() );
        chainFileListFilter.addFilter(new RegexPatternFileListFilter("(?i)^.+\\.xml$"));
        src.setFilter(chainFileListFilter);
        return src;
    }

    @Bean
    public UnZipTransformer unZipTransformer() {
        UnZipTransformer unZipTransformer = new UnZipTransformer();
        unZipTransformer.setExpectSingleResult(false);
        unZipTransformer.setZipResultType(ZipResultType.FILE);
        unZipTransformer.setDeleteFiles(true);

        return unZipTransformer;
    }

    @Bean("agentdemographicsplitter")
    public UnZipResultSplitter splitter() {
        UnZipResultSplitter splitter = new UnZipResultSplitter();
        return splitter;
    }

    @Bean
    public DirectChannel outputChannel() {
        return new DirectChannel();
    }

    @Bean
    public DirectChannel aggregatorOutputChannel() {
        return new DirectChannel();
    }

    @Bean("confirmChannel")
    public DirectChannel confirmChannel() {
        return new DirectChannel();
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageHandler fileOutboundChannelAdapter() {
        FileWritingMessageHandler adapter = new FileWritingMessageHandler(new File(outputDir));
        adapter.setDeleteSourceFiles(true);
        adapter.setAutoCreateDirectory(true);
        adapter.setExpectReply(true);
        adapter.setLoggingEnabled(true);
        return adapter;
    }


    @Bean
    public MessageHandler confirmationfileOutboundChannelAdapter() {
        FileWritingMessageHandler adapter = new FileWritingMessageHandler(new File(confirmDir));
        adapter.setDeleteSourceFiles(true);
        adapter.setAutoCreateDirectory(true);
        adapter.setExpectReply(false);
        adapter.setFileNameGenerator(defaultFileNameGenerator() );
        return adapter;
    }

    @Bean
    public TaskExecutor taskExecutor() {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        executor.setCorePoolSize(corepoolsize);
        executor.setMaxPoolSize(maxpoolsize);
        executor.setQueueCapacity(queuedepth);
        return executor;
    }

    @Bean
    public DefaultFileNameGenerator defaultFileNameGenerator() {
        DefaultFileNameGenerator defaultFileNameGenerator = new DefaultFileNameGenerator();
        defaultFileNameGenerator.setExpression("payload.name");
        return defaultFileNameGenerator;
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow confirmGeneration() {
        return IntegrationFlows.
                from("confirmChannel")
                .handle(confirmationfileOutboundChannelAdapter())
                .get();
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow individualProcessor() {
        return flow -> flow.handle("thirdpartyIndividualAgentProcessor","processfile").channel(outputChannel()).handle(fileOutboundChannelAdapter());
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow firmProcessor() {
        return flow -> flow.handle("thirdpartyFirmAgentProcessor","processfile").channel(outputChannel()).handle(fileOutboundChannelAdapter());
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow thirdpartyAgentDemographicFlow() {
        return IntegrationFlows
                .from(inputFileSource(), spec -> spec.poller(Pollers.fixedDelay(scanFrequency,TimeUnit.SECONDS)))
                .channel(MessageChannels.executor(taskExecutor()))
                .<File, Boolean>route(f -> f.getName().contains("individual"), m -> m
                        .subFlowMapping(true, sf -> sf.gateway(individualProcessor()))
                        .subFlowMapping(false, sf -> sf.gateway(firmProcessor()))
                        )
                .channel(aggregatorOutputChannel())
                .aggregate(aggregator -> aggregator.groupTimeout(messageGroupWaiting).correlationStrategy(new CorrelationStrategy() {

                    @Override
                    public Object getCorrelationKey(Message<?> message) {
                        return "xyz";
                    }
                }))
                .channel(aggregatorOutputChannel())
                .handle("agentDemograpicOutput","generateAgentDemographicFile")
                .channel(confirmChannel())
                .get();
    }
}
```

Below is the log

```
2018-09-07 17:29:20.003 DEBUG 10060 --- [ taskExecutor-2] o.s.integration.channel.DirectChannel    : preSend on channel 'outputChannel', message: GenericMessage [payload=C:\thirdpartyintg\input\18237232_firm.xml, headers={replyChannel=org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate$TemporaryReplyChannel@1a867ae7, errorChannel=org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate$TemporaryReplyChannel@1a867ae7, file_name=18237232_firm.xml, file_originalFile=C:\thirdpartyintg\input\18237232_firm.xml, id=dd70999a-8b8d-93d2-1a43-a961ac2c339f, file_relativePath=18237232_firm.xml, timestamp=1536366560003}]
2018-09-07 17:29:20.003 DEBUG 10060 --- [ taskExecutor-2] o.s.i.file.FileWritingMessageHandler     : fileOutboundChannelAdapter received message: GenericMessage [payload=C:\thirdpartyintg\input\18237232_firm.xml, headers={replyChannel=org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate$TemporaryReplyChannel@1a867ae7, errorChannel=org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate$TemporaryReplyChannel@1a867ae7, file_name=18237232_firm.xml, file_originalFile=C:\thirdpartyintg\input\18237232_firm.xml, id=dd70999a-8b8d-93d2-1a43-a961ac2c339f, file_relativePath=18237232_firm.xml, timestamp=1536366560003}]
2018-09-07 17:29:20.006 DEBUG 10060 --- [ taskExecutor-2] o.s.integration.channel.DirectChannel    : postSend (sent=true) on channel 'outputChannel', message: GenericMessage [payload=C:\thirdpartyintg\input\18237232_firm.xml, headers={replyChannel=org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate$TemporaryReplyChannel@1a867ae7, errorChannel=org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate$TemporaryReplyChannel@1a867ae7, file_name=18237232_firm.xml, file_originalFile=C:\thirdpartyintg\input\18237232_firm.xml, id=dd70999a-8b8d-93d2-1a43-a961ac2c339f, file_relativePath=18237232_firm.xml, timestamp=1536366560003}]
2018-09-07 17:29:20.006 DEBUG 10060 --- [ taskExecutor-2] o.s.integration.channel.DirectChannel    : postSend (sent=true) on channel 'firmProcessor.input', message: GenericMessage [payload=C:\thirdpartyintg\input\18237232_firm.xml, headers={replyChannel=org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate$TemporaryReplyChannel@1a867ae7, errorChannel=org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate$TemporaryReplyChannel@1a867ae7, file_name=18237232_firm.xml, file_originalFile=C:\thirdpartyintg\input\18237232_firm.xml, id=0e6dcb75-db99-1740-7b58-e9b42bfbf603, file_relativePath=18237232_firm.xml, timestamp=1536366559761}]
2018-09-07 17:29:20.007 DEBUG 10060 --- [ taskExecutor-2] o.s.integration.channel.DirectChannel    : preSend on channel 'thirdpartyintgAgentDemographicFlow.channel#2', message: GenericMessage [payload=C:\thirdpartyintg\output\18237232_firm.xml, headers={file_originalFile=C:\thirdpartyintg\input\18237232_firm.xml, id=e6e2a30a-60b9-7cdd-84cc-4977d4c21c97, file_name=18237232_firm.xml, file_relativePath=18237232_firm.xml, timestamp=1536366560007}]
2018-09-07 17:29:20.008 DEBUG 10060 --- [ taskExecutor-2] o.s.integration.channel.DirectChannel    : postSend (sent=true) on channel 'thirdpartyintgAgentDemographicFlow.channel#2', message: GenericMessage [payload=C:\thirdpartyintg\output\18237232_firm.xml, headers={file_originalFile=C:\thirdpartyintg\input\18237232_firm.xml, id=e6e2a30a-60b9-7cdd-84cc-4977d4c21c97, file_name=18237232_firm.xml, file_relativePath=18237232_firm.xml, timestamp=1536366560007}]
2018-09-07 17:29:20.009 DEBUG 10060 --- [ taskExecutor-2] o.s.integration.channel.DirectChannel    : postSend (sent=true) on channel 'thirdpartyintgAgentDemographicFlow.subFlow#1.channel#0', message: GenericMessage [payload=C:\thirdpartyintg\input\18237232_firm.xml, headers={file_originalFile=C:\thirdpartyintg\input\18237232_firm.xml, id=13713de8-91ce-b1fa-f52d-450d3038cf9c, file_name=18237232_firm.xml, file_relativePath=18237232_firm.xml, timestamp=1536366559757}]
2018-09-07 17:29:26.009  INFO 10060 --- [ask-scheduler-9] o.s.i.a.AggregatingMessageHandler        : Expiring MessageGroup with correlationKey[processdate]
2018-09-07 17:29:26.011 DEBUG 10060 --- [ask-scheduler-9] o.s.integration.channel.NullChannel      : message sent to null channel: GenericMessage [payload=C:\thirdpartyintg\output\17019222_individual.xml, headers={file_originalFile=C:\thirdpartyintg\input\17019222_individual.xml, id=c654076b-696f-25d4-bded-0a43d1a8ca97, file_name=17019222_individual.xml, file_relativePath=17019222_individual.xml, timestamp=1536366559927}]
2018-09-07 17:29:26.011 DEBUG 10060 --- [ask-scheduler-9] o.s.integration.channel.NullChannel      : message sent to null channel: GenericMessage [payload=C:\thirdpartyintg\output\18237232_firm.xml, headers={file_originalFile=C:\thirdpartyintg\input\18237232_firm.xml, id=e6e2a30a-60b9-7cdd-84cc-4977d4c21c97, file_name=18237232_firm.xml, file_relativePath=18237232_firm.xml, timestamp=1536366560007}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all the `RegexPatternFileListFilter` should be first in the `ChainFileListFilter`. This way you won't overhead a memory in the `AcceptOnceFileListFilter` for files which you are not interested in.

You need `.channel(confirmChannel())` in the end of the `thirdpartyAgentDemographicFlow` because this one is an input to your `confirmGeneration` flow.

I don't think that you `.channel(aggregatorOutputChannel())` at all it has to implicit.
You also don't need that `.channel(outputChannel())` in the sub-flows.

> this is not working

Please, elaborate more: what error you get, how then it works etc...
You also can share some DEBUG logs for the `org.springframework.integration` to determine how your messages travel.

Also it would help a lot if your share some simple Spring Boot project on GitHub to let us to play with and reproduce according your provided instructions.

**UPDATE**

Also I've noticed that your aggregator is based on the `groupTimeout()`. To make it to send aggregated message to downstream you also need to configure there this:

```
/**
 * @param sendPartialResultOnExpiry the sendPartialResultOnExpiry.
 * @return the handler spec.
 * @see AbstractCorrelatingMessageHandler#setSendPartialResultOnExpiry(boolean)
 */
public S sendPartialResultOnExpiry(boolean sendPartialResultOnExpiry) {
```

It is `false` by default, so your messages indeed are sent to the `NullChannel`.
See more info in the Docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/messaging-routing-chapter.html#agg-and-group-to

Comment: If I don't have the .channel(outputChannel()) how fileOutboundChannelAdapter() will get the files to archive.

Comment: If I comment both the .channel(aggregatorOutputChannel()) handle .handle("agentDemograpicOutput","generateAgentDemographicFile") is not getting invoked. I am not getting any error but it is not doing anything.

Comment: I don't know what is `archive` in your flow, but you definitely don't need channels in between if they just `DirectChannel`s: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/java-dsl.html#java-dsl-basics

Comment: Archive will copy the files from processing location to another location. fileOutboundChannelAdapter() does the job taking file object from the channel

Comment: Well, you need to be more explicit in your code then, I just don't see any `archive` word in your code...

Comment: We this test-case to prove that the feature works: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/blob/master/spring-integration-core/src/test/kotlin/org/springframework/integration/dsl/routers/RouterDslTests.kt#L115

Comment: individualProcessor() and firmProcessor() subflows does that at the end of the processing

Comment: You have somewhere a `NullChannel`: that's suspicious. You don't show something else to us... Is it really a problem for you to share project with us to let us to play? This discussion is getting anxious...

Comment: See an UPDATE in my answer.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I removed the unnecessary channels.